# Adding spotify track to playlist returns 401

Tags: angular, typescript, spotify

I'm creating a project in Angular where I'm playing with the Spotify API. But when I want to add a song to my playlist I'm getting an 401 response.

```
addTrackToPlaylist(songID: string, authToken: string) {
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken);
this.searchUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/6VO88OLaELcJxNhwwIgxam/tracks?uris=spotify:track:' + songID;

return this.http.post(this.searchUrl, { headers })
.pipe(map((response: any) => response));
}
```

Response:

```
error: {status: 401, message: "No token provided"}
```

[image]

But the token is set?

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of `post` is for the payload, not the headers.  The third parameter is for `httpOptions`.  You're currently setting the authorization header in the body.

```
const body = {};
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
  });
};

return this.http.post(this.searchUrl, body, httpOptions)
.pipe(map((response: any) => response));
```

https://angular.io/guide/http